# Eclipse/Android/Library - Can't find any R. references 

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got an Android Library which contains all of my applicable source code. I then have two projects that reference this library. One for the 'free' version, the other for the 'Paid' version of my app.

Up until recently, both were working great. I had my OS drive crash and re-installed my OS. After re-installing Eclipse and importing my workspaces, my 'Paid' can't reference the built-in "R" object in the same way my 'Free' app can.

Here's the applicable portion of the project layouts:

```
- Library
-- res
--- strings.xml
---- allow string

- PaidApp
-- res
--- layout
---- main.xml

- FreeApp
-- res
--- layout
---- main.xml
```

Additionally, both the Paid and the Free app hosts a single Activity. In both instances, this activity displays content from each app's respective 'Main' layout. The same activity reads strings from the Library's strings.xml file:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    String someString = getString(R.string.allow);

    ...
}
```

In the case of the Free app, the above works awesome. However, in the case of the Paid app, the `main` portion of `R.layout.main` is unresolved as well as the `allow` portion of `R.string.allow`

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem...

I had copy/pasted some code from another area and Eclipse added an `import android.R;` to my class. That reference was blowing away access to my internal `R` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Paid app project still references the library project (Properties -> Android). If it is, remove it hit apply then re-add it. Then do a clean on the Paid app.

I've had this problem too... it seems to happen when I exit Eclipse, somehow the Android project references get broken.